# Does GStreamer also implement communication protocols?

Tags: video-streaming, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I'm new to gstreamer and I need to use it in my project with video streaming from a robot to a stationary pc using a raspberry pi. Is it possible to implement communication protocols with gstreamer, i.e like handshake and etc. If yes, could you also explain how or a link would be great :D. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You can use the udpsrc/sink or tcpsrc/sink and send custom event over them to implement you communication protocol, but I am not sure what advantage over doing plain sockets it would give you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Gstreamer does not have any inbuild signaling layer or protocol. Gstreamer handels only Media transmission audio and video. 
There are some opensource signaling stacks projects that use gstreamer as media layer, but i am sure you would find that so complicated and confusing that you would forget about using it or developing it for that matter.You can check out this project here [Telepathy-farstream](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Farstream/)

Finally i would suggest you to use socket programming to design your very own simple signaling application. you can use `TCP/IP sockets.`